# Sketching the region of integration and writing an equivalent double integral and evaluating it.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The question says to sketch the region of integration and reverse the order of integration and then evaluate if possible.

$$\int_{0}^{\sqrt{3}}\int_{0}^{\tan^{-1}(y)}\sqrt{xy}dxdy$$

This is what I graphed as the region of integration:

[image]

So when I reverse the order of integration I get:

$$\int_{0}^{\tan^{-1}(\sqrt{3})}\int_{\tan x}^{\sqrt{3}} \sqrt{xy} dy dx$$

$$=\int_{0}^{\tan^{-1}(\sqrt{3})} \sqrt{x}\frac{2}{3}y^{3/2} \Bigg|_{\tan x}^{\sqrt{3}} dx$$

$$=\int_{0}^{\tan^{-1}(\sqrt{3})}  \frac{2}{3}\sqrt{x} \Bigg[3^{3/4}-(\tan x)^{3/2}\Bigg]dx$$

$$=\frac{2}{3}\int_{0}^{\tan^{-1}(\sqrt{3})} 3^{3/4}\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x}(\tan x)^{3/2}dx$$

I don't know what to do next to evaluate the integral.  Can someone please help me? The question says to find the value of the integral if possible, so does that mean I cannot find the value of this integral? If so, why not?